# Uncaught TypeError: current.distance is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, typeerror

I'm developing a little game of nothing at all more commonly called "Pathfinding"; and I am crashing on a small error that I have never encountered (I am young dev);

I have searched everywhere but I do not understand why this error appears.

I am experiencing this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: current.distance is not a function
> at search_min_distance (pathfinding.js:127)
> at game (pathfinding.js:151)
> at HTMLDocument. (pathfinding.js:173)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


const NBR_POINT = 10;
const MIN_SPACING = 100;
const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;

class point {
    constructor(x, y, name, id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.part = document.createElement("div");
        this.part.className = name;
        this.part.id = id;
    }

    distance(cmp) {

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cmp.x - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(cmp.y - this.y, 2));

    }
}

function random(mode) {

    if (!mode)
        return Math.random() * ((WIDTH - 100) - 100) + 100;
    else
        return Math.random() * ((HEIGHT - 100) - 100) + 100;
}

function printPoint(stk, crt) {

    var block = 0;

    do {

        block = 0;
        var x = random(0);
        var y = random(1);

        if (stk.length != 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < stk.length; i++) {
                if (x < (stk[i].x + MIN_SPACING) && x > (stk[i].x - MIN_SPACING) && y < (stk[i].y + MIN_SPACING) && y > (stk[i].y - MIN_SPACING)) {
                    block = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (block == 1);

    var ids = stk.length + 1;

    if (crt == "current")
        var p = new point(x, y, "point courant", ids);
    else
        var p = new point(x, y, "point", ids);

    p.part.style.bottom = p.y + "px";
    p.part.style.left = p.x + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(p.part);

    return p;

}

function polyPoint() {

    var stk = new Array();

    for (let i = 0; i < NBR_POINT - 1; i++) {
        stk.push(printPoint(stk, null));
    }
    printPoint(stk, "current");

    return stk;

}

function imp_session() {

    var dark_status = sessionStorage.getItem('dark_mode');

    if (dark_status == 1)
        document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
    if (dark_status == 0)
        document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");

}

function srv_DarkMode() {

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {

        let keypress = event.key;

        var dark_status = sessionStorage.getItem('dark_mode');

        if (keypress == "d") {

            if (dark_status == null) {
                dark_status = 0;
                sessionStorage.setItem('dark_mode', dark_status);
            }

            if (dark_status == 1) {
                this.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
                dark_status = 0;
                //To be able to delete sessions and not add them afterwards and error duplicate key.
                sessionStorage.removeItem('dark_mode');
                sessionStorage.setItem('dark_mode', dark_status);

            } else {
                this.body.classList.add("darkmode");
                dark_status = 1;
                //To be able to delete sessions and not add them afterwards and error duplicate key.
                sessionStorage.removeItem('dark_mode');
                sessionStorage.setItem('dark_mode', dark_status);
            }
        }
    });
}

function search_min_distance(stk, current) {

    let min = current.distance(stk[0]);
    let tmp;
    let real = min;

    for (let i = 1; i < stk.length; i++) {
        if (stk[i].id = current.id)
            continue;
        tmp = current.distance(stk[i]);
        if (tmp < min)
            real = i;
    }

    return real;

}


function game(stk) {

    var cp = document.getElementsByClassName('courant');

    cp[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        alert("txt");
    });
    var distId = search_min_distance(stk, cp[0]);

    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('point');

    for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (p[i].id != cp[0].id || p[i].id != distId) {
            p[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                alert("txt");
            });
        }
    }


}

function init() {
    imp_session();
    srv_DarkMode();
    return polyPoint();
}
game(init());
});
```

-> current and stk [0] are indeed of "type" point.

All the remaining code does not seem important to me, but if necessary I will provide it.

I thank you in advance ! Be indulgent...

Comment: log current inside search_min_distance function, you will get a better idea, also add the code from where search_min_distance function is called.

Comment: It's done, I thank you in advance, I added all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The point you are getting using the getElement function just returns
> the js object, it does not contain any functions from the class.

You need to create a new class instance from this obtained point as follows inside the search_min_distance function

```
const { x, y, name, id } = current;
const currentPoint = new Point(x, y, name, id);
let min = currentPoint.distance(stk[0]);
```

I suggest you write a util function to calculate the distance between two points, passing the two points as arguments. It will be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I think to approach it in a static way it will be better I think. But I thought using my point's instance was easier, actually not.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `distance` function to `this` inside `constructor`

```
class point {
    constructor(x, y, name, id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.part = document.createElement("div");
        this.part.className = name;
        this.part.id = id;
        // bind distance method
        this.distance = this.distance.bind(this);
    }

    distance(cmp) {

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cmp.x - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(cmp.y - this.y, 2));

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same error .. thanks you for the reply

Comment: you can change this line `let min = current.distance(stk[0]);` to this `let min = stk[0].distance(current);` ,because `stk` is type of the `point` object and `current` is type of the `DOM` element

Answer (score 0):

The name of error is "TypeError". And That's not just for fun. Possible problems in search_min_distance:

1. stk is not defined or its length is 0
2. stk is not array of points (typeof point[])
3. point is not defined or it's not point (typeof point)
   Sure problems:
4. point.id is not defined, it's only in point.part

```js
if (stk[i].id = current.id)
```

to

```js
 if (stk[i].part.id = current.part.id)
```

Your code is only errors.

Comment: As I told you, I am a novice in JS, I never understood why the experienced ones are so hard with the novices, I know that for you it is very simple, but you have been here. Thank you for your intervention and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally all this for a simple mistake of inattention; I took dom for my array and put an assignment where there should have been an equal .. thanks everyone.

```
  if (stk[i].id = current.id)
```

as

```
  if (stk[i].id == current.id)
```

and

```
var distId = search_min_distance(stk, cp[0]);
```

as

```
var distId = search_min_distance(stk, stk[cp[0].id]);
```